# Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 2 was incorrect on entry to ZGEHD2

Tags: warning-messages, eigenvalues

I have some code which is diagonalising very large random matrices, and storing certain statistical properties of their eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

The code runs fine on my computer. When running it on a cluster, to access larger matrix size, it *occassionally* (but by no means consistently---maybe 20% of the time) produces nonsense output (i.e. the code runs, but produces numbers which cannot be correct due to basic mathematical bounds).

Producing nonsense seem to coincide with an error code being printed

```
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 2 was incorrect on entry to ZGEHD2.
```

Unfortunately, I have not managed to narrow down the precise source of the error as (i) I have only encountered the error when diagonalising extremely large matrices (~ 4hrs per diagonalisation), (ii) computational time is not free, (iii) that the error does not occur consistently, and (iv) it does not seem anyone else using Mathematica has seen this error before.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? Or have any ideas on how to find/work around the error.

Version: `12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`

System: `Linux x86 (64-bit)`

OS: `Unix`

Comment: I would contact Wolfram support. Does the other system perhaps also run mkl libraries with another software stack?